# Make a textitem fill with color according to the time

Tags: android

I was wondering whether it would be possible to have a textview (or something similar), and make it fill with color depending on the time. For example, if the time was 7:30, there would be a number 8 filled halfway with color. At 7:35 it would be filled a little bit more. I've never seen an idea like this in any android app, so I'm not sure if it's even supported by the android SDK. Would I have to resort to using images and change the picture depending on the time?

something similar to this: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's sure is possible.

You can either use images as you mentioned, have two images - one is full scale black, and the other is an image slowly revealing with the help of some kind of [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or animation with [Property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

The other possible way is [drawing the digit on a canvas](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/). in that case you'll ofcourse have to use the desired font, and then draw the text upon the canvas. then you can play with the canvas size to create the effect of partial color.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do it one of those methods and see how it turns out